# What do I need to do CUDA development on Windows 10?

Tags: visual-studio, cuda

I've installed the CUDA 10.2 tools on Windows 10 along with Visual Studio Community Edition.  When I run the nvcc compiler on a .cu file from the command line it complains that it cannot find cl.exe, which apparently is a Microsoft compiler.  If cl.exe is part of VSCE it didn't get put on the PATH.  Maybe there are additional steps that I don't know about

Also, VSCE doesn't know what .cu files are and I can't find any extensions for NVidia or CUDA.

Does VSCE support CUDA development, or do I need the commercial edition or something else to get going with CUDA development on Windows?

Update:

I tried building one of the sample projects (CUDA Samples\v10.2\1_Utilities\deviceQuery) by importing it into VSCE and it fails with this message:

```
Error   MSB4019 The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 10.2.props" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 10.2.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#introduction

Comment: @talonmies - that doesn't mention anything about where the cl.exe is installed (if it is installed by VSCE).  It mentions a 2015 community edition, but nothing about the current VSCE.

Comment: Not mentioning something is a pretty good indication of not being supported.....

Comment: Well, no.  It's supported, but temporarily broken: 
 https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition/Content/Using_VS_2019.htm

Comment: You don't seemed to have grasped that VS and VS community edition are not the same thing. VS2019 is supported. The VS2019 community edition is not

Comment: I installed the professional edition and it doesn't have CUDA support either.  Worse yet, the installation didn't pickup the Nvidia Nsight extension which I have installed on my system.  The community edition does have the NSight extension, but it doesn't do any good.  I can't create a CUDA project in either one.  Thanks, Microsoft.

Answer (score -2):

The [solution is here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1049524/cuda-setup-and-installation/cannot-run-samples-on-ms-visual-studi-2019/).  The CUDA installation guide fails to mention that you have to copy several files from the CUDA installation to the VSCE installation.